Стык союза и союзного слова в вопросительном предложении

Вот как с басурманами разговаривать, и что у них на уме, как
распознаешь?

Нужна ли запятая после «разговаривать»? С одной стороны, имеем во второй части присоединение (?) по типу «Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, я не знаю», с другой, по правилу, части ССП, соединенные союзом «и», не разделяются запятой при вопросительной интонации.

Правильно:
Вот как с басурманами разговаривать и что у них на уме, как распознаешь?
Пояснение
Это СПП с  однородными изъяснительными придаточными, поэтому нет запятой перед союзом И. Главная часть относится к обоим придаточным. Вопросительный характер предложения не имеет значения.
§ 35. Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточным, пункт 3
Дополнение
Вариант правки: Вот как с басурманами разговаривать и что у них на уме, разве распознаешь?
Оригинал:
— Согласен с тобой. Жаль только, оружия у нас нет никакого — себя защищать. Вот как с ними, басурманами, разговаривать и что у них на уме как распознаешь?
Пропущена запятая.

Спасибо! Не угадал здесь структуру СПП, хотя теперь она стала очевидной. Для меня вторая часть была чем-то вроде инверсии. В голове сидел вариант: «Вот как с басурманами разговаривать и как распознаешь, что у них на уме?» Как будто бы предложение можно прочитать так, что последняя часть относилась бы только к предпоследней, а не к двум? Или это невозможно?

Для этого предложения это невозможно из-за наличия вопросительных местоимений КАК и ЧТО, приходится считать их однородными придаточными.  Сравнить: Сложно разговаривать с басурманами, и что у них на уме, как распознаешь? Сложное предложение, сочинительная и подчинительная связь. Вопросительный знак относится ко второй части предложения.
